# What is the function of "{}" in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am reading [xargs: How To Control and Use Command Line Arguments](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/), and find the following example:

```
{} as the argument list marker
......
$ find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/old.files
```

I can't figure out the exact meaning and function of `{}` in `bash shell`, could anyone give a detailed explantion?

Comment: Did you try reading the manual for xargs where it tells you exactly how it works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used as a program name or argument, `{}` has no particular meaning or usage in the `bash` or other Bourne syntax based shells. It is simply left unchanged and passed to the utility. Technically, nothing even forbids a program to be called `{}`.

On the other hand, the `find` utility `-exec` clause is using `{}` to represent the matched file(s), eg:

```
find /tmp -name "*.txt" -exec ls -l {} +
```

For consistency with find, `{}` is also used by default or explicitly with `xargs` to represent the string to be replaced.

```
ls /tmp/*.txt | xargs -I {} ls -l {}
```

Note that xargs is useless in the example you cite as find can already do what is expected itself:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -exec mv {} ~/old.files \;
```

Comment: So `{}` only has special meaning in `find ... exec` command, in other `bash shell` cases, it has no particular meaning, and just a common literals. Right?

Comment: That's indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

It's right there in your question:

> **{} as the argument list marker**

It's being used as a marker (placeholder) for the argument list. E.g., that's where the arguments will be put in the command line. So for instance, if you had two files matching `*.bak` (`one.bak` and `two.bak`), the commands `xargs` would generate would be:

```
mv one.bak ~/old.files
mv two.bak ~/old.files
```

Just a paragraph or two further down:

> You can rename {} to something else. In the following example {} is renamed as file. This is more readable as compare to previous example:
>
> ```
> $ find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mv file ~/old.files
> ```

The article doesn't bother to tell you, but it's using the `-I` option to change the marker string. From `info xargs`:

> '-I REPLACE-STR'
>
> '--replace[=REPLACE-STR]'
>
> '-i[REPLACE-STR]'
>
> Replace occurrences of REPLACE-STR in the initial arguments with
> names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
> terminate arguments; instead, the input is split at newlines only.
> If REPLACE-STR is omitted (omitting it is allowed only for '-i'),
> it defaults to '{}' (like for 'find -exec').  Implies '-x' and '-l
> 1'.  The '-i' option is deprecated in favour of the '-I' option.

Answer (score 2):

`{}` is a keyword for xargs.Your cmd means find all the `*.bak` file.And give each `.bak` filename to xargs as `{}` (using -I {} option).So you can use the filename as a argument here.

For example. If the find cmd gives you the output of

> 1.bak
>   2.bak
>   3.bak

Each filename here gives to `xargs` as `{}`. So the `mv {} ~/old.files` will translate into

> mv 1.bak ~/old.files
>   mv 2.bak ~/old.files
>   mv 3.bak ~/old.files

Assume that you want to rename each `.bak` file to `.bak.2015-04-01`.You have to use the filename twice in your mv cmd.

> mv 1.bak 1.bak.2015-04-01

You can make that happen by using

`find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} {}.2015-04-01`

Comment: It's not a keyword to xargs, it's just what most people set -I to.

Comment: @JID `{}` not only what most people set `-I` to but also what `xargs` uses by default when `-i` option argument is omitted.

Comment: @jlliagre I know, it's still not a keyword though.